# lsc function on compact set it attains its maximum minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Is this true if so how to show it? if not true can you give a counter example:

A lower semicontinuous function f on a compact set K attaings its minimum on K.

A lower semicontinuous function f on a compact set K attains its maximum on K.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is lsc., it attains its minimum on a compact $K$.

Recall that $f$ is lsc. iff $f^{-1}(\alpha,\infty)$ is open for all $\alpha$ iff $f^{-1}(-\infty, \alpha]$ is closed for all $\alpha$.

Let $m = \inf_{x \in K} f(x)$, and let $C_n = f^{-1}(-\infty, m+\frac{1}{n}] \cap K$. It is straightforward to see that $C_n \subset K$ is closed, and $\{C_n\}$ has the finite intersection property (by properties of $\inf$). Hence $\cap_n C_n$ is non-empty, and if $x \in \cap_n C_n$, $f(x) \le m$, hence $f(x) = m$.

To see that the maximum is not necessarily attained, let $g(x) = x 1_{(0,1)}(x)$, and $K = [0,1]$. Then $\sup_{x \in K} g(x) = 1$, but $g(x) <1$ for all $x$.